# Coding Annual Quantiles of Data

Tags: r, quantile

I have a data frame called "baseline_2030s_Simulation_df", which has data as per below:

```
         name       run  year  hyear     date     Qsim
         <chr>     <int> <dbl> <int>     date>   <dbl>
 1 baseline_2030s     1  1961  1961 1961-01-01 0.01174578
 2 baseline_2030s     1  1961  1961 1961-01-02 0.05649294
 3 baseline_2030s     1  1961  1961 1961-01-03 0.53905528
 4 baseline_2030s     1  1961  1961 1961-01-04 0.47176994
 5 baseline_2030s     1  1961  1961 1961-01-05 1.14605700
 6 baseline_2030s     1  1961  1961 1961-01-06 2.00960733
 7 baseline_2030s     1  1961  1961 1961-01-07 1.67644775
 8 baseline_2030s     1  1961  1961 1961-01-08 1.37355507
 9 baseline_2030s     1  1961  1961 1961-01-09 1.11827576
10 baseline_2030s     1  1961  1961 1961-01-10 0.91294671
# ... with 547,840 more rows
```

There are a total of 50 "runs", with each run having a "Qsim" data at daily time steps. The time period for each "run" is identical (01.01.1961 - 31.12.1990).

I require to calculate the Annual Q70 for "Qsim" for each year in each run. Q70 is the Qsim value which is exceeded 70% of the time.

So for example I need to calculate and store the value of Q70 for Run 1 - Year 1961, Run 1 - Year 1962....all the way to Run 50 - Year 1990.

I can calculate the Q70 value for the entire data set (i.e. not annualy or by run) with the code below, but struggled to convert this to a annual/ by run alternative.

```
baseline_2030s_Simulation_df %>% group_by(name, run, hyear) %>% 
summarise(Q70 = quantile(Qsim, 0.3))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem as your code's output returns by(year-run) observations: you have a "1961 run 1" Qsim, a "1962 run 2" Qsim and so on. Do you have any issue? :)

Comment: yes I have Qsim for each day and each run, however I need the Q70 quantile calculated annual for the 30 years in all 50 runs.

Comment: We need some example data to help you. The code looks okay at first glance